# ref selector in ExtJs view?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I was trying to use a ref and selector approach for setting / showing/ hiding a field on one of the tabs in a 6 tab panel. It throws an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get method
> for selector.'

Is ref selector only to be used in a controller? I dont want to use Ext.getCmp() or Ext.ComponentQuery.query(). They are not recommended to use approach by ExtJs guys. We can use ref and selector in controller with out any problem by specifying the view in the views[] part and ref and selector in refs[] part. ref : 'x'  selector:'xyz #x'   this.getX()...

I followed the same method for referring a field inside a view. It fails. Why so? What are the other possible ways to set, hide and show fileds in other tabs not by Ext.getCmp() or Ext.ComponentQuery.query()...

Thoughts and suggestions are always welcome! thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe refs are only available from within a controller.  The recommended practice is using the [down](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-down) method. It works just like the component query except it only finds children of the component it is called from. So something like this should work.

```
YourTab.down('#fieldItemId').hide();
```

Comment: Hello, thx for ur response. I tried this approach. But, how do u define a ref to "YourTab". For simplicity lets consider we have 2 tabs. In tabOne how do I refer tabTwo?

Comment: `this.up('tabpanel').down('tabTwo #tabTwoFiled').hide();` is the way.

Answer (score 1):

It appears in sencha docs that adding a `ref` is adding the method to the controller.  So it would not be available outside the controller.  Additionally, the method is actually internally executing `Ext.ComponentQuery`.  Please see [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs) for the information in sencha docs regarding `refs`

Comment: I agree. So, what is the fuss about using Ext.getCmp('id'); directly? This case study [here](http://www.akawebdesign.com/2012/07/26/case-study-locating-extjs-components/) is interesting.

Comment: @MBK Very Interesting Article!